# Проблема с Django url

Tags: python, python-3.x, django

view must be a callable or a list/tuple in the case of include().

File "F:\python\bookmarks\account\urls.py", line 5, in  
url(r'^login/$', 'django.contrib.auth.views.login', name='login')

проект-bookmarks
приложение - account

settings.py

```py
import os

from django.urls import reverse_lazy

LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = reverse_lazy('dashboard')
LOGIN_URL = reverse_lazy('login')
LOGOUT_URL = reverse_lazy('logout')

# Build paths inside the project like this: os.path.join(BASE_DIR, ...)
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))


# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/howto/deployment/checklist/

# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
SECRET_KEY = '5s7k#$)$002*3irlm+ed5kn!qy14wd3ih4v-6dw1xj97$(_n$!'

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = []


# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'account',
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'bookmarks.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'bookmarks.wsgi.application'


# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/settings/#databases

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db.sqlite3'),
    }
}


# Password validation
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/settings/#auth-password-validators

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]


# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True


# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/howto/static-files/

STATIC_URL = '/static/'
```

views.py

```py
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.contrib.auth import authenticate, login
from .forms import LoginForm
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required


@login_required
def dashboard(request):
    return render(request, 'account/dashboard.html', {'section': 'dashboard'})


def user_login(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = LoginForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            cd = form.cleaned_data
            user = authenticate(username=cd['username'], password=cd['password'])
            if user is not None:
                if user.is_active:
                    login(request, user)
                    return HttpResponse('Authenticated successfully')
                else:
                    return HttpResponse('Invalid login')
    else:
        form = LoginForm()
    return render(request, 'account/login.html', {'form': form})
```

forms.py

```py
from django import forms


class LoginForm(forms.Form):
    username = forms.CharField()
    password = forms.CharField(widget=forms.PasswordInput)
```

bookmarks/urls.py

```py
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path
from django.conf.urls import include, url

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    url(r'^account/', include('account.urls')),
]
```

account/urls.py

```py
from django.conf.urls import url
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^login/$', 'django.contrib.auth.views.login', name='login'),
    url(r'^logout/$', 'django.contrib.auth.views.logout', name='logout'),
    url(r'^logout-then-login/$', 'django.contrib.auth.views.logout_then_login', name='logout_then_login'),
    url(r'^$', views.dashboard, name='dashboard'),
]
```

Comment: Вы не смогли перевести ошибку?

Comment: В urlpatterns на месте вьюхи нужно прописывать функцию, а вы прописали строки

Comment: @SergeyGornostaev не смог понять как ее исправить

Comment: @andreymal то есть мне нужно прописать функции в views?

Comment: То есть в urls.py надо импортировать django.contrib.auth.views.login и убрать кавычки.

Comment: @SergeyGornostaev в строке import django.contrib.auth.views.login                          ошибка - No module named 'django.contrib.auth.views.login'; 'django.contrib.auth.views' is not a package

Comment: @SergeyGornostaev первую ошибку я исправив заменив                                      
      path(r'^login/$', 'django.contrib.auth.views.login', name='login'),          на                   
      path(r'^login/$', views.login, name='login'), но с logout не так не работает

Answer (score 0):

У вас django 2-й версии. Там нужно использовать path везде

Подробнее: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/http/urls/#example

Comment: не помогло та же ошибка